# How do I see the number for an unknown caller who is not in my contact list?

Tags: iphone, caller-id

I have an iphone 4 and although I get a notification for a missed call but i cant see the number of the person calling all it shows is missed call from "unknown" i cant find anything on the internet regarding a fix or a setting? please help, if a person calls me and they're not in my contact list i can never call back cause i don't know who called? this is extremely frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Whether the caller's number shown or not does not depend on your contact list. It is the information which is provided by the carrier (AND the caller because the caller can disable it and you won't see any number even if the caller is in your contact list).
If you see "unknown" that means the CallerID was not provided. If it's provided then you would see the number of the callers even if they're not in your contact list.